# No data in MQL query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, monitoring

I created a Google Cloud function that executes a database query and returns a count:

```
import psycopg2

def my_function(request):
  """Runs a custom SQL query on a Cloud SQL database and returns the result."""

  # Connect to the Cloud SQL database.
  conn = psycopg2.connect(host='<YOUR_DATABASE_HOST>', database='<YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>', user='<YOUR_DATABASE_USER>', password='<YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD>')

  # Create a cursor.
  cur = conn.cursor()

  # Run the custom SQL query.
  cur.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> WHERE <YOUR_FIELD> IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(<YOUR_FIELD>)) = ''')

  # Fetch the result of the query.
  result = str(cur.fetchone()[0])

  # Close the cursor and connection.
  cur.close()
  conn.close()
  print("Some text:" + result)

  # Return the result of the query.
  return result
```

I tested it, works fine, returns the corect value. Then I created a Log-based metric of type distribution, with the filter:

```
resource.type="type" 
resource.labels.function_name="function" 
resource.labels.region="region"
severity=DEFAULT
"Some text"
```

And a regex on the textPayload field to extract only the value: `\b(\d{8})\d`

Then I try to set up an alert using the MQL Query:

```
fetch k8s_container::logging.googleapis.com/user/Name-Of-Metric
| align delta(5m)
| group_by [], [value_Collector_mean: mean(value.Metric)]
```

And if I run the query, I get the message:

> No data is available for the selected timeframe

If I use the filter I set in the log-based metric in the Logs Explorer I receive the corect inputs. These were generated by me using the function testing option multiple times. I want to set a scheduler to run this function once every 2 hours and if the value has increased then I want to get an alert.

Why does it say there is no data available for the selected timeframe if I can clearly see data in the logs explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation and the result that you are having,  the metric counts might be delayed. Even though countable log entries appear in the Logs Explorer, it may take up to 10 minutes to update the log-based metrics in Cloud Monitoring. Attached is the link for troubleshooting log-based metrics that can be of help for your use case.[1]

[1]

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/troubleshooting#slow-startup